# How to configure NLog in app.config in .net 6 to write on 2 different targets?

Tags: rest, http, logging, nlog, .net-6.0

I want to configure NLog to write in a file and also to send the logs via http sink to an application i build which saves the logs also in database.
How is done the configuration of  NLog in app.config, in a .Net 6 Rest api to write to both targets in the same time?
I am using this configuration:

```json
"rules": [
      {
        "logger": "*",
        "minLevel": "Info",
        "writeTo": "logfile"
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Notice that you can specify multiple target-names for `writeTo=`. Ex. `"writeTo": "logFile, logConsole" }`

Comment: See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-configuration-with-appsettings.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution worked for me:

```
"rules": [
      {
        "logger": "*",
        "minLevel": "Info",
        "writeTo": "logfile"
      },
        {
        "logger": "*",
        "minLevel": "Debug",
        "writeTo": "http"
      },
    ]
```